# How can I able to connect my qt program to remote database in qt (mysql database of another computer)

Tags: mysql, qt

I have an application in qt and it is connected to the local database using the following codes

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("Dictionary");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("yamuna");
bool ok = db.open();
```

Now want I wanted is I want to connect this program to a database to a remote computer with ip 10.10.12.3

I create the database Dictionary and import all tables on 10.10.12.3 's

I changed the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` of my local computer as follows

```
bind address=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind address=10.10.12.3
```

and used the following code in Qt

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("10.10.12.3");
db.setDatabaseName("Dictionary");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("yamuna");
bool ok = db.open();
```

But it gives the error as

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.10.12.3' (111) QMYSQL: Unable to connect

Please help me.

Comment: Is your server reloaded? Try some mysql remote client. Read the logs of the server

Comment: This could well be a networking issue, but it's hard to tell given the information. What kind of server are you trying to connect to? (It's been a while since I did any network support, but I seem to remember 10.%.%.% to be private, so I'm assuming the server is in your LAN/WAN. Do you have control of its config?)